# A simple HTML file wouldn't show on Android full screen

Tags: android, html, webview

I have tried calling

`zoomIn();`

`setBuiltInZoomControls(true);`

`supportZoom(true);`

etc but it just wouldn't work.

Just a hint... when I double-click on the text it does fit the screen but no wrap.

Any lead given will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "wouldn't work"?

Comment: i mean the text wouldnt fit different screens. the text is shown on the top left side of the screen. the smaller the screen is the more sqeezed the text is towards top left

Comment: ... I think you're doing this wrong. You don't magically get a responsive website because you enabled zoom...

Comment: so sunshine what do you suggest how should i do it? internallt stored html file in a webview which can fit various screen sizes.

Comment: Please be more precise, can you send a piece of code so it would be easier to help you?

Comment: setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

myWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
myWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/new2.html");

Comment: android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   tools:context=".MainActivity" >
  <WebView android:id="@+id/webview"                                                                                    
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

Comment: sorry its not allowing me to format the code for some reason.

Comment: @Harris Code formatting doesn't work in comments beyond just fixed font. You can edit your question and put it in there.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added a Viewport Meta tag?

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

If the HTML body is set to 100%, the text should automatically fill the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Hi try the following code :

```
    public class Terms extends Activity {
    WebView mWebView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.terms); 

    this.mWebView = ((WebView)findViewById(R.id.mWebView));     
    this.mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
    this.mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(false);
    this.mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false);
    this.mWebView.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.CLOSE);
    this.mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/Terms.html");
    Button  back_btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.back);
    back_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            finish();
        }
    });

  }
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private class Callback extends WebViewClient {
      @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
      return(false);
    }
  }  
}
```

Comment: THanks a lot lads....These four magic lines worked for me    myWebView.setInitialScale(1);  
  myWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
  myWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
  myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());